# What is a good desktop *nix aside from Linux, *BSD, and OS X?

Tags: distribution-choice

What other common or semi-common or simply not super-rare *nixes are there in desktop use aside from distributions of Linux, various BSDs and Mac OS X?

Comment: This is going to hang on the definition of “super-rare”. “None” is a defensible answer, but it'll surely offend some of the users of these “super rare” unices.

Comment: Do proprietary systems count? E.g. SCO? (sheesh, that felt like saying Voldemort, off to iron my hands)

Comment: Does Haiku (http://haiku-os.org/) Count?  Not sure it can technically be called *nix.

Comment: Is OpenSolaris a BSD variant, or is it non-BSD/Linux?

Comment: "OpenSolaris is a descendant of the UNIX System V Release 4 (SVR4) codebase developed by Sun and AT&T in the late 1980s. It is the only version of the System V variant of UNIX available as open source." https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Open_solaris

Comment: [GNU/GNU Hurd](http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd.html). :)

Comment: @Apophenia: You are going to need to edit this to be much more specific about what you want to know and less restrictive about how it can be answered, otherwise it's going to get closed as a subjective / non productive question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solaris, or [OpenSolaris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSolaris).

A fairly interesting UNIX successor is the research OS [Plan 9 from Bell Labs](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/plan9/index.html).